# Copy a file to a Windows remote machine from Linux using java.nio.file.Files.copy()

Tags: java, nio, network-share

I am working on a Spring Boot application and I need to copy a file to a remote machine.

When I run the program on a Windows machine, it works fine. Here is the code:

```
void copyImage(MultipartFile image, String name) {

    name = name + "." + FileUtils.getExtension(image);

    Path path = Paths.get("\\<remote-machine>\path\to\repository\" + name);

    try {
        Files.copy(image.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception here
    }
}
```

As expected, this program doesn't work when I run it on Linux (Pop!_OS). I believe the argument passed to `Paths.get()` is not properly formatted, since Windows and Linux treat paths differently. Any idea how to make this method work on Linux?

Comment: `\\` is the windows path separator. Try `/` instead as starting point. Also note that `remote machine\path` is probably a very specific windows thing. Meaning: by default, you do not have access to the file system of a remote system. It seems that you are using some sort of mechanism to make the remote file system locally available like that. So, this is really bigger than just "how to write down the path". For "just a path" to work, that remote FS needs to be available to you.

Comment: Linux never uses \ as file separators, nor does it use UNC paths. The closest thing you may get is by mounting a CIFS volume e.g. https://support.zadarastorage.com/hc/en-us/articles/213024986-How-to-Mount-a-SMB-Share-in-Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux does not support [UNC paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths) natively - it does not understand that such a path is meant to refer to a network share. You have several options:

- use a Java library that implements network share access using the SMB protocol. Some of the actively supported libraries are [JCIFS](https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs) and [SMBJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj). This should make your application portable (you can run it both on Linux and Windows), but you depend on an additional library and must use its custom API to access remote files
- mount the remote share on Linux as a CIFS volume ([official Ubuntu guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)). Then the remote share becomes accessible as if it was a local directory on Linux. In this case you can keep using `java.nio` to access/copy files, but need to make sure to make the root path to your share configurable (eg. `\\host\share` on Windows and `/mnt/share` on Linux).

Comment: Thanks. The second option fits my case better.